How to deploy Azure CI/CD to deploy solution that has 2 sqlproj
I have CI/CD pipeline that deploy .Net MVC Web App to web Server.
The release task has
"D:\Deployments\sqlpackage-win-x64-en-162.2.111.2\sqlpackage.exe"
 /a:publish /targetservername:test.server
 /targetdatabasename:testuser 
 /targetuser:$(DBUsername) 
 /targetpassword:$(DBPassword) 
 /sourcefile:"$(System.artifactsdirectory)\Test-YAML\drop\DB\test-dbproj.dacpac" 
 /profile:"$(System.artifactsdirectory)\Test-YAML\drop\DB\PublishProfiles\test_database_dbproj.publish.xml"

I want to understand that how build pipeline will generate  /sourcefile:"$(System.artifactsdirectory)\Test-YAML\drop\DB\test-dbproj.dacpac"
similarly
/profile:"$(System.artifactsdirectory)\Test-YAML\drop\DB\PublishProfiles\test_database_dbproj.publish.xml"
I dont see any task on build pipeline that publish dacpac or test_database_dbproj.publish.xml.
The Test.sln does not have *.sqlproj and Test-db.sln has 2 sqlproj. what task to be added in build to publish dacpac or any other and use that in release pipeline to deploy as given above or any other approach.
 parameters:
- name: buildConfiguration
  default: ''

jobs:
- job: BuildTest
  pool:
    vmImage: 'windows-2019'
  steps:
  - checkout: self
    clean: true
    fetchDepth: 1 # Fetch only one commit

  - task: NuGetCommand@2
    displayName: 'Nuget Restore'
    inputs:
      command: 'restore'
      restoreSolution: '**/Test.sln'
      feedsToUse: 'select'
  
  - task: DeleteFiles@1
    displayName: 'Delete NuGet PDB Files Package'
    inputs:
      SourceFolder: '$(UserProfile)\\.nuget\\packages'
      Contents: '**/*.pdb'

  - task: DeleteFiles@1
    displayName: 'Delete NuGet PDB Files Source'
    inputs:
      SourceFolder: '$(Build.Repository.LocalPath)'
      Contents: '**/*.pdb'

  - task: MSBuild@1
    inputs:
      solution: '**/Test.sln'
      configuration: '${{ parameters.buildConfiguration }}'
      msbuildArguments: '/T:Build /p:DeployOnBuild=True  /p:WebPublishMethod=FileSystem /p:DeleteExistingFiles=True  /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true /p:PackageLocation="$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)\\Web" /p:TransformConfigFiles=true /p:ExcludeFoldersFromDeployment="SqlServerTypes" /p:DebugSymbols=false /p:DebugType=None'

  - task: CopyFiles@2
    displayName: 'Copy Report Files to: $(build.artifactstagingdirectory)\\Reports'
    inputs:
      SourceFolder: Test.Reports
      Contents: '*'
      TargetFolder: '$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)\\Reports'
      condition: succeededOrFailed()

  - task: CopyFiles@2
    displayName: 'Copy Database Report Deployment Script'
    inputs:
      SourceFolder: Deployment
      Contents: '*'
      TargetFolder: '$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)\\Reports'
      condition: succeededOrFailed()

  - task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
    inputs:
      PathtoPublish: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
      ArtifactName: 'drop'
      publishLocation: 'Container'



I want to understand that how build pipeline will generate /sourcefile:"$(System.artifactsdirectory)\Test-YAML\drop\DB\test-dbproj.dacpac" similarly /profile:"$(System.artifactsdirectory)\Test-YAML\drop\DB\PublishProfiles\test_database_dbproj.publish.xml"

According to your release task, the dacpac file and publish profile are in the $(System.artifactsdirectory) , which is the artifact directory of your classic release pipeline. I am guessing that you added your build pipeline(CI) as an artifact of your release. And have published dacpac file and profile as build artifact in your CI pipeline. Test-YAML is the source alias of your release artifact and drop is the name of the artifact published in build pipeline.
To run scripts as shown in your release task, you should put the dacpac and profile in DB folder and copy this folder to $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory) before PublishBuildArtifacts@1 task. The dacpac is generated in MSBuild@1 task. The publish profiles are usually created in Visual Studio manually, you can put it into the repo.
I would suggest you share the structure of the drop artifact in your build summary page to help us better understand how release consumes the build artifact. About "The Test.sln does not have *.sqlproj and Test-db.sln has 2 sqlproj", I am not sure what the relation between these two solutions. If you want to build Test-db.sln, just add a MSBuild@1 task and copy the dacpac files to $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory).
You can view the log of MSBuild@1 task to check the details about how dacpac is generated.

Update:
The root cause of the issue: The build artifact of the release pipeline comes from another yaml file instead of the one shared in the question. At the same time, set the properties of publishprofile to deploy always

Thanks @Ziyang Liu-MSFT for the response. The Pipeline setup for Test.sln fpr both CI and CD but that database seed data and db insertion in one project and schema in another project and it is part of Test-db.sln nlot in Test.sln. so when i deploy Test.sln, database changes also deployed. The current build pipeline, i dont see any build on Test-db.sln that generates the dacpac which was used in release pipeline. so Mu question if I want to add a task in build pipeline to build and publish that what task to be added.

How the current deployment task is working without corresponding build task which generated dacpac

I dont see anything that generates dacpac in build pipeline in build log

Can you share this info? 1. The screenshot of the artifact of your release pipeline. 2. The screenshot of the drop artifact folder structure of your build pipeline. You can see it from your build summary page.

Found the another template that is executed.

This is consistent with my guess. The build artifact of your release pipeline comes from another yaml file.

The solution has one SQL database project with Publish Profile folder has for each environment dev.publish.xml. Add another SQL Project to solution with Publish Profile for Dev.publish.xml. The build pipeline has MSBuild and publish task. MSBuild is for sln. The old project publish.xml is deployed to a drop but new is not getting deployed. I don't know what should I do to deploy new project publisher since no where project is referred in build pipeline. Please advise if I have to configure anything in the project.


"The old project publish.xml is deployed to a drop but new is not getting deployed" - You can copy the new project's publish profile to the $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory) folder before publishing artifact. Then use it in the release pipeline. 2. "I don't know what should I do to deploy new project publisher since no where project is referred in build pipeline" - Your solution has two SQL projects. In your MSBuild task, if you add solution in the input parameter solution, all  projects will be built.


found the issue. Set the properties of publishprofile to deploy always. Thanks for the response

Thanks for sharing your solution. I have updated it to the answer to help others may have the same question.
